# Automatically Delete a mysql field

Tags: android, mysql

I am developing an android application which is connected to the online database developed using **mysql**. 
I have provided the user to enter a time slot (ex. 10.00AM - 12.00PM), Day(Tuesday). And what I need is to delete the field when current date matches to the day and passed the time slot. (ex.Tuesday && 12.01PM).

How can I to write a query to **delete the field automatically** when the day and time matches the current day and time.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You could use [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events.html) or Cron job

Comment: Thanx for the reply s.  I will implement a code using a Corn job.

Answer (score 1):

Write a cron job that will run at the required time to do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` DROP COLUMN `columnname`
```

Answer (score 0):

following query works fine for delete the record based on current timestamp.

> DELETE FROM table
>       WHERE datecolumn = date('Y-m-d h:i A');  //'2012-05-05 10:00PM'

Comment: Thanx for the replay. I will implement the code and report the results.